# Are explicitly thrown exceptions thrown upwards?

Tags: java, exception

Disclaimer: I don't have access to a java compiler nor could i install IDE's, my workspace does not give me sufficient privileges.

I'm trying to understand how Java deals with exceptions and stumbled upon this question:

If a subclass explicitly throws an exception within a catch block that catches all exceptions, is it thrown up? For example consider the following lines of code:

```
public Class someClass  {
    public int value;
    public someClass()  {
        value = 1;
        try {
            value ++;
            if(value == 2)  {
                throw new Exception("value is 2");
            }
        }   catch   (exception e)   {
            System.out.println("I caught an exception.");
            throw new Exception("Does this exception get thrown upwards?");
            System.out.println("will this line of code get printed after the previously thrown exception?");
        }   finally {
            return;
        }
    }
}

public class anotherClass   {
    public static void main throws Exception{
        someClass someclass = new someClass();  // will this class catch the second explicitly thrown exception?
    }
}
```

So a new Exception is thrown in the try block, caught by the following catch block. Where does the second throw statement go? Does it go upwards into the calling class if there is one? Also, will the println statement get executed after the exception is thrown even though it's not in the finally block?

Thanks.

Comment: You already have the code. Why don't you run it and see what happens?

Comment: Yes, the second one bubbles up and the `println` statement after throwing will not be executed. A good IDE will show that second `println` as unreachable code. Try Eclipse and the FindBugs plugin.

Comment: @ThomasWeller my current work computer does not have java and I don't have privileges to install Java, nor do could i contact the admin.

Comment: @noobcoder http://ideone.com/ lets you execute java code

Comment: @k5_ wow.. thanks.. the internet is a great place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where does the second throw statement go? Does it go upwards into the
>   calling class if there is one?

Yes, Exception will be thrown to the caller method, in your case, it is `main()` method.

> Will the println statement get executed after the exception is thrown
>   even though it's not in the finally block?

Yes, `System.out.println("I caught an exception.")` will be executed and then the Exception object will be thrown to the caller (i.e., `main()`), so in your catch block, the below line is unreachable.

```
System.out.println("will this line of code get 
              printed after the previously thrown exception?");
```

---

The important point is that you can always use `exception.printStackTrace()` (inside the `catch` block) **to check how the exception has been propagated** across the method stack. I suggest you try this so that you will clearly see how the exception has been propagated across the methods.

I suggest you refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace()) and understand clearly how the method chain gets executed.

Also, the other point that you might be interested in is that when the `main()` method throws the exception (i.e., either `main()` itself or through a chain, whatever be the case), then **JVM catches the exception and shuts down**.

Answer (score 1):

Although probably not intended, the exception will *not* be thrown up in that specific case, which you can also see by the missing `throws` clause in the constructor of `someClass`.

The reason is the `return` statement in the `finally` block, causing java to discard the exception (and a good IDE to give you a "finally block does not complete normally" warning).

More specifically, [section 14.20.2 of the specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2) states that:

> If the catch block completes abruptly for reason R, then the finally
>   block is executed. Then there is a choice:
>
> - If the finally block completes normally, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason R.
> - If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason S (and reason R is discarded).

With *reason S* being the `return` statement and *reason R* being the `throw new Exception("Does this exception get thrown upwards?");`.

You can see yourself [on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/1Ovyoo):

```
class someClass {
    public int value;

    public someClass() {
        value = 1;
        try {
            value++;
            if (value == 2) {
                throw new Exception("value is 2");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("I caught an exception.");
            throw new Exception("Does this exception get thrown upwards?");
        } finally {
            return;
        }
    }
}

class anotherClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            someClass someclass = new someClass(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
I caught an exception.
```

But for the purpose of this question, javaguy's answer already covers the general point well enough.